# Sed one liner not working in python subprocess

Tags: python, json, shell, sed, subprocess

I am trying to incorporate this sed command to remove the last comma in a son file.

```
sed -i -e '1h;1!H;$!d;${s/.*//;x};s/\(.*\),/\1 /' file.json"
```

when i run this in the command line, it works fine. When i try to run as a subprocess as so it doesn't work.

```
   Popen("sed -e '1h;1!H;$!d;${s/.*//;x};s/\(.*\),/\1 /' file.json",shell=True).wait()
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It doesn't work because when you write `\1`, python interprets that as `\x01` and our regular expression doesn't work / is illegal.

That is already better:

```
check_call(["sed","-i","-e",r"1h;1!H;$!d;${s/.*//;x};s/\(.*\),/\1 /","file.json"])
```

because splitting as a real list and passing your regex as a *raw* string has a better chance to work. And `check_call` is what you need to just call a process, without caring about its output.

*But* I would do even better: since python is good at processing files, given your rather simple problem, I would create a fully portable version, no need for `sed`:

```
# read the file
with open("file.json") as f:
   contents = f.read().rstrip().rstrip(",")  # strip last newline/space then strip last comma
# write back the file
with open("file.json","w") as f:
   f.write(contents)
```

Answer (score 0):

In general, you might try the following solutions:

1. Pass the raw string, as was mentioned
2. Escape the '\' character.

This code also does what you need:

```
Popen("sed -e '1h;1!H;$!d;${s/.*//;x};s/\(.*\),/\\1 /' file.json", shell=True).wait()
```

or

```
try:
    check_call(["sed", "-i", "-e", "1h;1!H;$!d;${s/.*//;x};s/\(.*\),/\\1 /", "file.json"])
except:
    pass # or handle the error
```

Comment: Would you have to also add a `...\...` in the `\\(` and `\\)`?